# Shift Reduce Parser Pseuducode

Tags: java

I've to implement the Shift Reduce Parser" in Java, can somebody suggest me a good link to pseudocode for this parser?

Comment: yes but couldn't find its pseudo code,Google gives references of books,i'm looking if somebody has  a link to the pseudo code

Comment: If this is homework please add the 'homework' tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google is your friend; [Introduction to Shift-Reduce Parsing](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~zdu/parsdemo/srintro.html) explains in detail.